# How can I install uriparser 0.9.3?

Tags: 18.04

I ran `sudo apt-get install liburiparser-dev` and got the following output:

```
liburiparser-dev is already the newest version (0.8.4-1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 630 not to upgrade.
```

I really need to be up to date with the latest library (0.9.3). Is it possible to ask the package maintainers to update the package?

Comment: Related: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upgrade to the latest version, please do the following:

1. Add the Ubuntu repository that contains the latest version `0.9.3-2`, run the following command in terminal:

   `echo "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main universe" | sudo tee -a  /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Update the repositories, run the following command in terminal:

   `sudo apt update`
3. Upgrade to the latest version, run the following command in terminal:

   `sudo apt install liburiparser-dev`

After this you should have the latest `liburiparser-dev` installed.

**CAUTION:**

At the moment 19.10 (Eoan) is pre-release -- it's still in testing. If you run into problems, we don't provide support for pre-release here. Also, one of the most common problems we help untangle is folks who have mixed sources from different releases of Ubuntu and broke their system, so we usually don't recommend it. Folks who want newer software should use a newer release of Ubuntu instead. It is strongly advised to **just upgrade the needed package** and remove the repository added above, once you have successfully upgraded the needed package. This can be done by editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and commenting out or removing that line and running `sudo apt update` afterwards.

**NOTE:**

To know which official Ubuntu repository contains the latest version of a certain package, you can search for it at [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/uriparser).

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. How did you know which repository contained the latest version? I ask for future reference with other packages I may wish to upgrade.

Comment: @JamesRead You are most welcome. I edited and added how to search the Ubuntu repositories to the answer.